# C Programming: How do I read terminal input if piping from stdin?

Tags: c, linux, stdio

So, I'm trying to write a c program that reads input piped into the program (through stdin), but I also need to be able to read input from the terminal (so I obviously can't read it from stdin). How would I do that?
I'm trying to open another file handle to /dev/tty like this:

```
int see_more() {
    char response;
    int rd = open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR);
    FILE* reader = fdopen(rd, "r");
    while ((response = getc(reader)) != EOF) {
        switch (response) {
            case 'q':
                return 0;
            case ' ':
                return 1;
            case '\n':
                return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

But that results in a segmentation fault.

Here's the version that works. Thanks for everyone's help :)

```
int see_more() {
    char response;
    while (read(2, &response, 1)) {
        switch (response) {
            case 'q':
                return 0;
            case ' ':
                return 1;
            case '\n':
                return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have piped something into your application and also get terminal input on `stdin`, since `stdin` as far as your program is concerned is the pipe.  You're going to need a different approach.  Is that your question?

Comment: Sorry, it throws a Segmentation fault.

Comment: @Carl: The "different approach" is what the asker is trying to use.

Comment: Have you tried opening it for read-only access instead of read/write?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense now.  I must have missed something on my first read-through.

Comment: Carl - If I cat a file and then pipe it into the more program, more will take input to enter down to another line, etc. more is written in c. That's what this program is, actually. I'm trying to duplicate the more program.

Comment: Are you showing us your real code?  `fdopen` expects a string as that second argument.

Comment: `getc` does not return a `char`; it returns an `int`.

Comment: @David: look into the source code of `more` or just `strace` to understand how it is doing things...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
FILE* reader = fdopen(rd, 'r');
```

should be

```
FILE* reader = fdopen(rd, "r");
```

Here is the prototype of [`fdopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen):

```
FILE *fdopen(int fildes, const char *mode);
```

It expects a `char*`, but you're passing it a `char`.

Comment: This answer explains the OP's segmentation fault, but I wonder why he didn't get a warning/error at compile time?

Comment: You're right, the single quotes were causing the segmentation fault (the first one). Now I'm getting a segmentation fault reading a char from the file pointer.

Comment: @AdamZalcman I just posted it. It's the response = getc(reader) part.

Comment: Well, the code as it looks now has two problems: `response` should be an `int` (this is what `getc()` returns) and there is no error handling. I don't see anything that'd result in a segfault, though.

Comment: Someone just suggested I do this: char input; read(2,&input,1); Which does the same thing (except that it works). This is reading from stderr instead of opening another pointer to /dev/tty.

Comment: If you really need an extra input channel, then `/dev/tty` is better and more customary than reading from stderr (intended for output). Try `read(rd, &input, 1);` instead. It just uses the file descriptor to `/dev/tty` you obtained with `open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR)`.

Comment: You should test that the result of `fdopen` is non-null.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another input piped in, then that will replace stdin (the terminal) with that input file. If you'd like to get input from the terminal, I'd suggest taking the file in as a parameter rather than a pipe, and then you can use stdin as normal.

Here's an example.

Execution:

```
./a.out foo.txt
```

Code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc >= 2)
    {
        char* filename = argv[1];
    }
    else
    {
        // no filename given
        return 1;
    }

    // open file and read from that instead of using stdin
    // use stdin normally later
}
```

Comment: Which is why the asker is opening `/dev/tty`.

Comment: My program also can open a file from the args, but that's not the question. I need to be able to pipe input into the program.

Comment: -1: you can have something piped into your program via stdin **and** read directly from `/dev/tty`.